# Проблема в хешах sha1 php c#

Tags: php, c#, хеширование

С#

```
string Salt = sha1(sha1("Test"));
string hash1 = sha1(sha1(INTERFACE.GetUserKey()));
string client = sha1(INTERFACE.GetUserKey() + hash1 + Salt);

public string sha1(string text)
{
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sh = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    sh.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    byte[] re = sh.Hash;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in re)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$Key = "605867360";
$salt =  sha1(sha1("Test"));
$hash1 =  sha1(sha1($Key));
$gen = $Key+$hash1+$salt;
echo $server_success = sha1($gen);
?>
```

Получается

- В C# = 2f08bd86fd4d506a8117de892a8e9df7675aab74
- В PHP = 75f98970800b3e97f87cb39ee35047700ef22bdc

Comment: Вероятно, кодировки разные...

Comment: На файле UTF-8 стоит

Comment: Но ведь считается-то не то, что в файле, а то, что в памяти. Выведи байтовые массивы, для которых делаешь вычисления и проверь, одинаковы ли они.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, вот тут такая же проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/c-sharp-sha-1-vs-php-sha-1-different-results
Дело в кодировке: "PHP uses ASCII charset for hash calculations."
Можно читать файл как UTF8, но перед применением хеширования нужно перевести в ASCII:
`sh.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));`

Comment: Прикол в том то что $salt и $hash1 совпадает с программой а вот это $server_success нет

Comment: Видимо код в php не правильно написал